# Retornar tags associadas aos posts

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Eu uso a query abaixo para retornar todos os posts marcados com a tag definida:

```
SELECT imprensa_posts.slug AS slug, tipo, titulo, data
FROM imprensa_posts 
JOIN imprensa_tags_posts ON imprensa_tags_posts.id_post = imprensa_posts.id_post 
JOIN imprensa_tags ON imprensa_tags.id_tag = imprensa_tags_posts.id_tag 
WHERE imprensa_tags.slug = 'tag-4' 
ORDER BY data DESC
```

Mas preciso também pegar todas as tags associadas a cada post retornado. Tentei dessa forma:

```
SELECT imprensa_posts.slug AS slug, tipo, titulo, data,
GROUP_CONCAT(imprensa_tags.slug) AS tag_slugs, GROUP_CONCAT(tag) AS tags
FROM imprensa_posts 
JOIN imprensa_tags_posts ON imprensa_tags_posts.id_post = imprensa_posts.id_post 
JOIN imprensa_tags ON imprensa_tags.id_tag = imprensa_tags_posts.id_tag 
WHERE imprensa_tags.slug = 'tag-4' 
GROUP BY imprensa_posts.id_post
ORDER BY data DESC
```

Mas não funciona. A query retorna tag-4 para todos os posts.

**UPDATE**

Recriei as tabelas no SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c04b/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E se você fizer algo assim

```
SELECT imprensa_posts.slug AS slug, tipo, titulo, data,
GROUP_CONCAT(imprensa_tags.slug) AS tag_slugs, GROUP_CONCAT(tag) AS tags
FROM imprensa_posts 
JOIN imprensa_tags_posts ON imprensa_tags_posts.id_post = imprensa_posts.id_post 
JOIN imprensa_tags ON imprensa_tags.id_tag = imprensa_tags_posts.id_tag 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM imprensa_tags it
              JOIN imprensa_tags_posts itp ON it.id_tag = itp.id_tag
              WHERE slug = 'tag-4' AND itp.id_post = imprensa_posts.id_post)
GROUP BY imprensa_posts.id_post
ORDER BY data DESC
```

O segredo está no `EXISTS`

```
EXISTS (SELECT * 
        FROM imprensa_tags it
        JOIN imprensa_tags_posts itp ON it.id_tag = itp.id_tag
        WHERE slug = 'tag-4' AND itp.id_post = imprensa_posts.id_post )
```

Ele só vai retornar aqueles que existerem essa `tag` relacionada.

-

Outra solução que pensei

```
SELECT imprensa_posts.slug AS slug, tipo, titulo, data,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(slug) 
        FROM imprensa_tags it
        JOIN imprensa_tags_posts itp ON it.id_tag = itp.id_tag
        WHERE itp.id_post = imprensa_posts.id_post) AS tag_slugs,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag) 
        FROM imprensa_tags it
        JOIN imprensa_tags_posts itp ON it.id_tag = itp.id_tag
        WHERE itp.id_post = imprensa_posts.id_post) AS tags
FROM imprensa_posts 
JOIN imprensa_tags_posts ON imprensa_tags_posts.id_post = imprensa_posts.id_post 
JOIN imprensa_tags ON imprensa_tags.id_tag = imprensa_tags_posts.id_tag 
WHERE imprensa_tags.slug = 'tag-4'
GROUP BY imprensa_posts.id_post
ORDER BY data DESC
```

Comment: Está retornando o mesmo resultado. Ambas as queries funcionam corretamente com exceção de um ponto: se determinado post está associado a uma tag que não é a informada no WHERE, esta não é mostrada nos GROUP_CONCATs

Comment: @marcelo2605 mas você não quer filtrar os posts somente aos que possuem a `'tag-4'` relacionado?

Comment: @marcelo2605 Acho que entendi o que você quis dizer, vou alterar pera.

Comment: @marcelo2605 Alterei o SELECT do `EXISTS`, da uma checada

Comment: Tem alguma coisa errada: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'itg.id_post' in 'where clause'

Comment: @marcelo2605 era `itp`, já corrigi.

Comment: Está retornando a mesma coisa. Ele retorna todos os posts vinculados a tag-4. Mas se o post está vinculado também a outra tag, esta na aparece nos GROUP_CONCATs

Comment: @marcelo2605 Você executou exatamente o exemplo que sugeri?

Comment: @marcelo2605 Coloquei outra solução com 2 `sub select`, da uma verificada.

Comment: Mesma coisa. Vou criar um SQL Fiddle e posto aqui.

Comment: @marcelo2605 Vai ajudar bastante :/

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta. Rode a primeira query e veja que o Release 2 está vinculado a duas tags (tag 1 e tag 7). Mas quando eu rodo a segunda query, só aparece a tag 1.

Comment: @marcelo2605 o primeiro select que eu fiz com `EXISTS` está correto não? aqui trouxe certo tag1 e tag7

Comment: @marcelo2605 Arrumei o com 2 `sub select`, agora está retornando igual o primeiro

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado.